# How to give a name to destructed object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Here is my code:

```
const { tourId, title, startLocation,endLocation, details: {days}} = info;
```

and how I used it

```
  <BookingHeader tourId={tourId} title={title} startLocation={startLocation} endLocation={endLocation} days={days}/>
```

I would like to give a name to the destructed object (bookingHeaderProps) so ideally I used it like

```
  <BookingHeader {...bookingHeaderProps}/>
```

Anybody know how to give name to destructed object?

Comment: Destructuring doesn't create an object at all, it creates a bunch of variables. If you want to pass an object, you'd have to do that manually.

Comment: If you want to pick or omit some properties from an object you could define corresponding helpers or use `pick` and `omit` functions from `lodash`.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely do not need a name, just use"{...this.props}", but if you did want to name it then you could always reconstruct the object yourself and pass that as props.

Comment: The reason is info object has a lot of properties and I don't want to pass down extra properties that I don't want to use.

Answer (score 0):

When you destructure

```
const { a, b } = c;
```

you don't get »one object« that you can name. You instead created *two* local variables, `a` and `b` that are now *separate*. You can combine them as keys of a combined (and named) object again like this:

```
const bookingHeaderProps = { tourId, title, startLocation, endLocation, days };
```

and then use

```
<BookingHeader {...bookingHeaderProps} />
```

The above step relies on [short-hand property names (ES2015)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer), so that has to be supported as well.